# How to add user input in dart test?

Tags: dart, dart-io, dart-test

I'm new to dart and trying out testing. My first programm is a command line tool that takes user input. How can I simulate that during testing?

My function lets the user choose an item out of a list. I'd like to write tests if the function successfully rejects integers too small or too big entered via "readLineSync".

How to create the input in a test?
(using test.dart)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `stdin` to collect input you can use `IOOverrides` to override the behavior of `stdin`. The example I'm using requires you to install `mocktail` as a dev dependency.
Given the funtion:

```dart
String? collect() => stdin.readLineSync();
```

I want to provide my own input during testing:

```dart
import 'dart:io' hide stdin;

import 'package:example/example.dart' show collect;
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

class FakeStdin extends Mock implements Stdin {}

void main() {
  test('collect returns input', () {
    final stdin = FakeStdin();

    when(() => stdin.readLineSync()).thenReturn('input!');

    IOOverrides.runZoned(
      () {
        expect(collect(), equals('input!')); // passes!
      },
      stdin: () => stdin,
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Having an extra dependency just for one test seems a bit much. Is that possible only using dart core functionality?

Comment: @JasonTS it is possible. But it will require a more leg work for this test and future tests with `Stdin` to create the fake responses you need. First, remove the `mocktail` dependecy. Next, only write your class as `class FakeStdin implements Stdin { ... }`. Third, override `noSuchMethod` in the `FakeStdin` class. Override the `readLineSync`  method to return the response you like to test with. Now you should be able to use an instance of this `FakeStdin`in the `IOOverrides`