# Stdin tests in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm creating tests for a dart project, as i'm learning to do them, but i'm strugling to create mockstdin to test when you require to type on terminal.

for eg.:

This test :

```dart
test(
        'lerStringComTexto should print the given text and read a string from stdin',
        () async {
      final input = 'hello world';
      final expected = input;
      final mockStdin = Stream<List<int>>.fromIterable([utf8.encode(input)]);
      stdin = mockStdin.asBroadcastStream();

      final result = await ConsoleUtils.lerStringComTexto('Enter a string: ');

      expect(result, equals(expected));
    });
```

shows this error:

```
'stdin' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
Try finding a different setter, or making 'stdin' non-final.dartassignment_to_final
```

Also tried

```dart
 test(
        'lerStringComTexto should print the given text and read a string from stdin',
        () async {
      final input = 'hello world';
      final expected = input;
      final mockStdin = Stream<List<int>>.fromIterable([utf8.encode(input)]);
      stdin = mockStdin.asBroadcastStream();

      final result = await ConsoleUtils.lerStringComTexto('Enter a string: ');

      expect(result, equals(expected));
    });
```

Comment: Instead of depending on `stdin` directly, pass it as a dependency into the class that needs it. Then you can pass in something else for your tests.

Comment: Where is the "'stdin' can't be used as a setter because it's final." error coming from?  You aren't attempting to *set* `stdin` anywhere in the code you've shown.  Also, the proper way to mock `stdin` is with `IOOverrides`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76039117/